# Фильтрация и сортировка на React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом лучше всего организовать фильтрацию и сортировку таблицы, используя React/Redux?

Подробно:

К примеру, таблица по товарам из четырёх колонок.
Первая - номер(id) товара, вторая - наименование, третья - тип и четвёртая - цена.

Говоря о **сортировке** - мне нужно при нажатии на ячейку **цена** товар сортировать исходя из стоимости, т.е. от дешёвого к дорогому и при повторном нажатии - наоборот, затем при ещё одном - сбрасывать сортировку.

А говоря о **фильтре**, так это при нажатии на ячейку **тип** выводить товары одного типа, остальные просто не отображать. Тип должен сменяться при повторных нажатиях на ячейку.

Comment: @Vasily подправил. Надеюсь, стало яснее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну я думаю идея следующая, берете state из которого формируется таблица, по сути это некий массив, копируете в переменную, далее пишите функции конкретно нужных вам сортировок, и сортируете скопированный из state массив. Написать функции можно ознакомившись в гугле " Как делать сортировку в JavaScript при помощи sort()" после того как функция отработала, обновляем state и все обновляется в таблице. Алгоритм примерно таков.